# Change Push Notification background color on Android 12

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-12

I want to achieve something like Myntra App Notifications where i can change the background color of my notification in Android 12

Since Android 12 have restricted custom notifications how can we set the color for whole notification?

[image: Myntra notification Android 12]

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly customize Push notifications. What you can do is override `onMessageReceived()` in your service that extends `FireBaseMessagingService`, and then create a **local** custom notification with whatever background color you want.

**Edit**: If you're asking how to apply a background color to local notifications, you need to set both of the following in the Notification Builder:

```
.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.yourBgColor))
.setColorized(true)
```

and if that doesn't work for some reason, you'll need to create a custom notification layout in XML with the background color you want, and then

```
.setCustomContentView(notificationView)
```

Comment: Yes want to know that how can you change bg color for your notification in android 12 as it has restrictions for custom notification.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12 custom notifications limitation. Also set colorized works when notification has media style or it is a foreground service notification. In my case foreground service cant be started from background thread for android 12

Comment: Have you actually tried setting a custom notification layout? If it doesn't work, you'll need to set `targetSdk=30`, or otherwise try to make it a media style notification. There is not 3rd option -- if it doesn't work, then Google made sure that's how they want it

Comment: I tried with custom layout and the above i mentioned that apps like myntra and VI have bg color on android 12 devices. Thats what i want to acheive

Comment: You can use custom notifications and Android 12 devices, but you need to configure your target SDK to be below Android 12.

Comment: not working.as i have created custom xml.